# Error al crear función con la clase splice vue js

Tags: vue.js, vue3, composition-api

Estoy intentado crear una lista de tareas con vue pero al pintar el componente me sale error en consola de la clase **splice**

Este es el componente logico `useTodo`

```
import { reactive, toRefs } from "vue";

export default function (){

    const data=reactive({
        todo:null,
        todos:[]
    })
    
    
    const addTodo=()=>{
        if(data.todo.length>1){
            data.todos.push(data.todo)
        }
        data.todo=null
    }
    const deleteTodo= (index)=>{
        data.todos.splice(index,1)
    }

    return {...toRefs(data),addTodo,deleteTodo}
}
```

Este es el componente de la vista `TodoList`

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h2>Lista de tareas</h2>
        <label for="todo">Todo</label><br>
        <input id="todo" v-model="todo" @keypress.enter="addTodo" />
        <ul>
            <li v-for="(t, index) in todos" :key="index">
                {{ t }} <span @click="deleteTodo(index)">X</span> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import useTodo from '@/composables/useTodo';

export default{
    name: "TodoList",
    setup(){
        const {todo,todos, addTodo,deleteTodo}=useTodo()
        return (todo,todos, addTodo,deleteTodo)
    }
}

</script>
```

Esta es el error que me genera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El valor de retorno de la función `setup()` debe ser **un objeto** no una lista de valores, es decir: está intentando retornar varios objetos y estos se concatenan a cadena de texto por ende el error. Para su componente `TodoList` siga:

```
setup(){
    const {todo,todos, addTodo,deleteTodo}=useTodo()
    return (todo,todos, addTodo,deleteTodo) ❌
}

setup() {
  const { todo, todos, addTodo, deleteTodo } = useTodo();
  return { todo, todos, addTodo, deleteTodo }; ✔️
}
```